# HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden when trying to run simple node server on Azure App service

Tags: node.js, azure, iis, backend, azure-appservice

I am new to azure app service and I am trying to deploy a basic ('Hello world') server for node.js. I am getting the following error after successful deployment on app services.

[image]

Also the checked the path mappings it seems to be pointing to right folder (containing index.js)

[image]

Default document is:  **index.html**

I used the following in web.config file to display the error

```
<configuration>
        <system.webServer>
            <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
            <asp scriptErrorSentToBrowser="true"/>
        </system.webServer>
        <system.web>
            <customErrors mode="Off"/>
            <compilation debug="true"/>
        </system.web>
    </configuration>
```

Also here is the simple server code :

```
const express = require("express");

const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.port || 5000;

app.get("/",(req,res)=>{
  return res.send("Networth tracker API")
})

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server running on PORT ${PORT}`);
});
```

**What am I missing here?**

Comment: Tutorials like https://halfblood.pro/running-nodejs-web-apps-on-iis-with-httpplatformhandler/ exist.

Comment: Could you kindly share the web configuration file?

Comment: Thanks you guys for help , I was able to run the server by recreating a Linux instance which does not require web config file, I am coming from AWS background lol

Comment: @AnugrahKumar Post your solution as answer so that it might help community having same type of issue.

Comment: @Naveen , its technically not a solution , I just found WA to go Linux route rather Windows IIS based